# Manual focus not consistent with Sony A7ii + Sony 55mm 1.8. Hidden setting?

Tags: lens, sony, manual-focus, sony-a7ii

I noticed that when I quickly turned my focus ring, the focus jump in focus was rather big: with a slight quick turn, I can almost jump between near focus and infinity. 
If I slowly turn the focus ring, it seems like I have to turn more to achieve the same focus distance.

For now I think this is by design, and there is a setting to enable/disable this behavior?

I hope my explanation is clear, it looks like the focussing is not linear, but is tied to how quick the ring is moving?

Comment: I think your lens has a fly-by-wire focusing system. If yes take a look at manual.

Comment: You are correct. Is there someway to make the handling linear?

Comment: Sorry, I looked everywhere I can. But couldn't find anything related setting it up...

Answer (score 1):

it seems like its a sort of function to help auto focus, I've noticed relatively similar results with a couple of my lenses, but obviously (from my icon), I'm a Nikon fanboy, so I have no experience with Sony equipment, but since my guess is its related to auto focus, do you have the auto focus function turned off on the lens itself as well as the camera body. but that's my best guess

Comment: There is no switch on this lens. I do think that must be the case indeed. Not really useful for filming though...

Comment: that's very unusual, I've never encountered a lens without a AF switch, sorry I couldn't be very helpful